# location.href is not working in script tag in html file. how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

`<script> location.href = "../views/test.html"; </script>`

it doesn't work in the Node.js project

main.html and test.html are in the same location

ESPractice/views/main.html
ESPractice/views/test.html

what should i do to fix it?

Comment: when should it be executed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `res.redirect('/test');` to redirect with Express.js. There is no location variable in Node.js.

Below is the similar code to your post.

```
app.get('/html', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/test');
})
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, "test.html"));
}
```

Comment: it works, but I want to know why location.href in the <script> tags in the html file doens't work.

Comment: location.href = "../views/test.html" -> then this will make your domain url like this.
https://localhost/..views/test.html.
It doesn't load test.html on Node.js.
So you must define routes for load test.html.